# Custom Slot with Numeric Data for Alexa Skills Kit

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

I'm writing an alexa skill for my local public transit directions. I'm defining the Train Stations with a custom slot like this -

```
LIST_OF_STOPS - 14th Street | 23rd Street | 33rd Street | Christopher Street | Exchange Place
```

I have a strong suspicion that Alexa is going to have a hard time understanding the ones like `14th Street`, is there documentation or guidelines around how these should be defined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not any documentation. Most people do it by trial and error. The only obscurely documented quirk is that "a.", "b.", etc can be used for the letters.

That being said, I think that those values look to be pretty OK. The one thing you need to be aware of is that Alexa takes the list of custom values "under advisement". It is not a definitive list. Alexa will happily return values other than what is on the list. So you are going to need a fuzzy matcher anyway so you can handle '23 street', and things like that.

I would try the simple list you have, and see if you are happy with the results. If not, you might make one intent that is {slot} street, another for {slot} place, etc. That might improve things. But it might not. You need to iterate and try a bunch of things and see.